# How to return both lower and uppercase vowels in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

I am attempting to write a function that accepts a string str and returns a new string consisting of just the vowels in str.

When writing this function, I'm passing all test except when the string has Capitalized vowels, because one test case requires me to pass the with Capitalize and lowercase vowels.

vowelsOnly("SHOUT it out"); // "OUiou"

am I missing something?

```
    const vowelsOnly = function (str) {
      let vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u']
      let newStr = ''
      for (let i of str.toLowerCase()) {
        if(vowels.includes(i)) {
           newStr += i
        }
      }
      return newStr
    }

vowelsOnly("hello world"); // "eoo"
vowelsOnly("happy birthday to you"); // "aiaoou"
vowelsOnly("SHOUT it out"); // "OUiou"
vowelsOnly("aieeeeeeeeou"); // "aieeeeeeeeou"
vowelsOnly("nvwlsnlycnsnnts"); // ""
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to update your logic so that `toLowerCase()` is called inside the iteration, rather than before:

```
for (let i of str) { // Remove toLowerCase() from this line

    if(vowels.includes(i.toLowerCase())) { // Place toLowerCase() here

       newStr += i // The character "i" retains original case
    }
}
```

That means you're not mutating the data that is returned, which will preserve the casing in your result:

```js
const vowelsOnly = function(str) {
  let vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
  let newStr = ''
  for (let i of str) {
    if (vowels.includes(i.toLowerCase())) {
      newStr += i
    }
  }
  return newStr
}

console.log(vowelsOnly("hello world")); // "eoo"
console.log(vowelsOnly("happy birthday to you")); // "aiaoou"
console.log(vowelsOnly("SHOUT it out")); // "OUiou"
console.log(vowelsOnly("aieeeeeeeeou")); // "aieeeeeeeeou"
console.log(vowelsOnly("nvwlsnlycnsnnts")); // ""
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Thus us what I initially thought, but did not implement it. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use a regular expression - match any character that isn't a vowel, and replace with the empty string:

```js
const vowelsOnly = str => str.replace(/[^aeiou]/gi, '');

console.log(
  vowelsOnly("hello world"), // "eoo"
  vowelsOnly("happy birthday to you"), // "aiaoou"
  vowelsOnly("SHOUT it out"), // "OUiou"
  vowelsOnly("aieeeeeeeeou"), // "aieeeeeeeeou"
  vowelsOnly("nvwlsnlycnsnnts") // ""
);
```

Comment: Wow, this could have been solved in one line of code? I have brush up on my regular expressions! Thanks for this!